# T-SQL: JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I query API and JSON output I want to save to a SQL Server 2016 table. Here is how I simulate transforming JSON output:

When I run this:

```
DECLARE @J NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"c":[4.935,4.935,4.9374,4.935,4.94],"t":[1643998980,1643999040,1643999100,1643999160,1643999220],"v":[1979,87494,9980,4382,17713]}';

SELECT [key] as jkey, value as c
FROM OPENJSON(@j, '$.c');
```

I get this:

```
jkey,c
0,4.935
1,4.935
2,4.9374
3,4.935
4,4.94
```

But I expect this:

```
jkey,c,t,v
0,4.935,1643998980,1979
1,4.935,1643999040,87494
2,4.9374,1643999100,9980
3,4.935,1643999160,4382
4,4.94,1643999220,17713
```

I spent hours and I could not figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Please add some background / context to this question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply join to the keys of the other keys.

> ```
> DECLARE @J NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"c":[4.935,4.935,4.9374,4.935,4.94],"t":[1643998980,1643999040,1643999100,1643999160,1643999220],"v":[1979,87494,9980,4382,17713]}';
>
> SELECT c.[key] as jkey, c.value as c, t.value as t, v.value as v
> FROM OPENJSON(@j, '$.c') c
> LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@j, '$.t') t ON t.[key] = c.[key]
> LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@j, '$.v') v ON v.[key] = c.[key]
> ORDER BY jkey;
> ```

> | jkey | c | t | v |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 4.935 | 1643998980 | 1979 |
> | 1 | 4.935 | 1643999040 | 87494 |
> | 2 | 4.9374 | 1643999100 | 9980 |
> | 3 | 4.935 | 1643999160 | 4382 |
> | 4 | 4.94 | 1643999220 | 17713 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6a067f70d706fb3374442912eb73a0fb)*

Comment: Thank You Very Much! It is exactly what I needed

Comment: @Vlad, if you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Comment: @Zhorov - I am new to Stack Overflow (and programming) and I just figured out that check-mark icon represents "Accept answer" and I just did that - Thanks!

Comment: @Vlad Thanks. Many new users overlook or ignore it. And your question was better than what the majority of the new users start with.